Exact search in elasticsearch vs search in list with one value
Is it any difference between exact search query for one value and search query IN list of value with one value.
Let me explain with sql notation.
E.g. for posgtres doesn't matter
Select "name" from any where id = '1'
or
Select "name" from any where id in ('1');
Postgres know how to do better. Me, as a developer, can always execute query with IN clause.
Is it matter for elasticsearch if it will be the same query semanticly?

You could use a runtime field in a search query to count length of the array with ids
Sample documents
PUT /one_item_array/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"id":[1,2,3,4]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"id":[1]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"id":[2]}

Search query with the runtime field. The first term query searches for documents with one id. The second term searches for documents containing id = 1
GET /one_item_array/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "id_count": {
            "type": "long",
            "script": {
                "source": "emit(params['_source']['id'].size());"
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id_count": {
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": {
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

